# How to enable Maven profile in VS code?

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ, we can run our integration tests by selecting the corresponding maven profile and provide vm args with active spring profile name using **-Dspring.profiles.active=e2e**

We are now moving to vs code where I was able to provide vm args in a launch.json file and that works, but where can I view list of maven profiles to select the integration profile?

Comment: There is no such interface, yet: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/465

Comment: Why moving from IntelliJ to VSCode for Java development... why do you need to activate a spring profile... ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maven vscode plugin (vscjava.vscode-maven) provides this interface

[image: maven vscode plugin interface]

The profiles you activate will be added to the command line when you launch Maven using the GUI.

Unfortunately the active profiles reset when you reload vscode.